# @Output event emitter not working

Tags: angular

I have a child component that emits an event like such...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rate-sort',
    templateUrl: './rate-sort.component.html'
})
export class RateSortComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    sortBy(string) {
        this.sort.emit(string);
    }

}
```

this should be passing the string invoked by a button on the template to the parent like such...

```
<header class="bg-white">
    <h4 class="text-primary my-0 mr-3">Media List Builder</h4>
    <div class="inner">
        ...
        <div class="wrapper">
            <app-rate-sort (onSort)="onSort($event)"></app-rate-sort>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="utility">
        ...
    </div>
</header>
```

and then in the parent component, i have a simple method for handling the event...

```
onSort(event) {
    this.sortKey = event;
    console.log(event);
}
```

however it seems that the parent is not getting the event, as the output in console is empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: thank everyone, I must be tired to not see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix,

Your output should be

```
@Output() onSort = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

also

```
sortBy(string) {
        this.onSort.emit(string);
 }
```

**EDIT**

As per **[`angular guidelines`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#dont-prefix-output-properties)**, don't use on with the ouput. just rename your event method as sort.

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <app-rate-sort (sort)="onSort($event)"></app-rate-sort>
 </div>
```

Comment: No, this goes against the Angular guidelines. Emitters should not carry the "on" prefix in the name. That's because there's also the alternative syntax to `(xxx)`, which would now be `on-onSort`, which looks clearly quite odd.

Comment: Just to leave a reference: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#dont-prefix-output-properties

Answer (score 2):

The event name has changed when you used it in the parent component.

Try (sort) not (onSort)

```
<header class="bg-white">
    <h4 class="text-primary my-0 mr-3">Media List Builder</h4>
    <div class="inner">
        ...
        <div class="wrapper">
            <app-rate-sort (sort)="onSort($event)"></app-rate-sort>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="utility">
        ...
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a event from a onSort event. But there is no event emmiter in your class for that.

you should change your parent component's template to this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <app-rate-sort (sort)="onSort($event)"></app-rate-sort>
</div>
```